# NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/timelineservice/collector/TimelineCollectorManager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Getting this error while I executed `start-all.cmd` command. Also I am unable to access http://localhost:8088 but I am able to acceess http://localhost:9870 
The error code below is from the Resource Manager command prompt

```
FATAL resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/timelineservice/collector/TimelineCollectorManager
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:688)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:380)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:399)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toInstance(BindingBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebApp.setup(RMWebApp.java:56)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApp.configureServlets(WebApp.java:160)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.build(WebApps.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:401)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startWepApp(ResourceManager.java:1137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:1245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1446)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.timelineservice.collector.TimelineCollectorManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 36 more
2018-06-30 15:32:39,168 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2018-06-30 15:32:39,169 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2018-06-30 15:32:39,169 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at HP/someipaddress
```

Comment: What version of Hadoop? Please show your environment variables for how you set the YARN classpath

Comment: Version of Hadoop is 3.0.3 and I have not set any Yarn class path. I have set java bin path, hadoop bin path and hadoop sbin path. I followed this tutorial on youtube to install hadoop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLVWrGGqGJU&lc=z22tgpmabufuebsgo04t1aokgq21lx3vlg1qd1z2ktsnbk0h00410.1530363325620441    If we have to set yarn class path can you tell me in a little more detail about how to set  or what would be the location of the yarn class. Thanks in advance

Comment: I stopped watching as soon as he copied some random files into the Hadoop binaries folder... That's wrong, not necessary, and probably will only work for Hadoop 2.7.6... Which would explain why you're getting errors... I can only guess he failed to explain how to get Winutils for any version of Hadoop

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 .You are right that video tutorial only works for Hadoop 2.7.6. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 51):

1. Use java version 1.8.x_xxx
   Verify java version in command prompt >java -version
2. copy "hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-3.x.x" from ~\hadoop-3.x.x\share\hadoop\yarn\timelineservice to ~\hadoop-3.x.x\share\hadoop\yarn folder.

the error disappears and the resource manager works fine.

Comment: this worked: copy "hadoop-yarn-server-timelineservice-3.0.3.jar" from ~\hadoop-3.0.3\share\hadoop\yarn\timelineservice to ~\hadoop-3.0.3\share\hadoop\yarn folder.
thanks

Comment: This worked like a charm! thank you. Upvoting the answer!

Comment: this really helped, as i don't see the need of having to install another java version